# Some questions about the pagination in PHP using Yii

Tags: php, css, yii, pagination

I am creating a gallery in my web page. In my web I also have some views in where I use some widgets like CGridView or CListView.  In these views, when there are many elements in the page, automatically appear a pagination bar. Of course I created theese views using Yii, and the problem is that I don't know how to create this kind of pagination in my gallery view. For this reason, I searched for a pagination code on internet and I found some things. Now I am using this code

```
<div class="pagination">
<ul>
<?php

echo "<a href=\"?pag=".'1'."\" onclick=\"Pagina('1')\">&lt;&lt; Primero </a> ";
if($pag_act>1) echo "<a href=\"?pag=".$pag_ant."\" onclick=\"Página('$pag_ant')\"> &lt; Anterior</a> ";

for ($l=$pag_act;$l<=$pag_ult;$l++){
echo "<a href=\"?pag=".$l."\" onclick=\"Página('$l')\"> $l</a> ";

}
  if($pag_act<$pag_ult) echo " <a href=\"?pag=".$pag_sig."\"    onclick=\"Pagina('$pag_sig')\">Siguiente &gt; </a> ";
echo "<a href=\"?pag=". $pag_ult."\" onclick=\"Pagina('$pag_ult')\">Último &gt;&gt;   </a>";

?>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Of course, I edited the code because I wanted that this display a pagination bar similar than the created by Yii in another views as I told you.

In the end, my pagination bar is similar the created by Yii but they don't work in the same way. For example, my pagination bar show "myApp/site/gallery.html?pag=1" in the URL, when I click a button it doesn't change his color background and the most important, when I click on a button the page is refreshed and you display the begining of this, I mean, the tittle, not the pagination bar.

I know that to change the background color I have to edit the css, in my case, in navi.css I have:

/* ----------------------------------------------Pagination-------------------------------------*/

```
.pagination{display:block; width:100%; text-align:center; clear:both;}
.pagination ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.pagination li{display:inline;}
.pagination .next{margin:0;}
.pagination a{display:inline-block; padding:2px 5px 3px 5px; margin:0 2px 0 0; border:1px solid #DFDFDF;}
.pagination .current, .pagination .splitter{padding:6px; margin:0 2px 0 0;}
.wrapper .pagination a:hover, .pagination .current, .pagination       .splitter{color:#9B9B9B!important; background-color:#F9F9F9;}
.pagination ul li.selected a{color:#666666!important; background-color: #F9F9F9;border:0;}
```

But I don't know that to do to change the background color of my pagination bar.

I would like that my pagination bar work as the created by Yii, or to know how to created another like the Yii pagination bar.

Please, someone could help me? ¡THANKS!

**EDIT:**

I use this code of gallery.php to display the images:

```
<div class="wrapper col2">
  <div id="container" class="clear">
    <!--     ####################################################################################################### -->
    <div id="tabcontainer">
      <ul id="tabnav">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Wedding Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Artistic Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Children's Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Fashion Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Action Photos</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- ########### -->
      <div id="tabs-1" class="gallery clear">
        <ul>
    
        <?php 

        while($imagen_a_empezar<$imagen_a_terminar){

                if($imagen_a_empezar>=$total_imagenes) break;
        
            if (in_array($imagen_a_empezar,$ultimos)){ 
            ?>
        
                <li class="last"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/images/portfolioslider/<?php echo     $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title=""><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/gallery/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                
        
            <?php }else{ ?> 
        
                <li><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/images/portfolioslider/<?php echo archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title=""><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/images/gallery/<?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
        
            <?php };?>

          <?php  $imagen_a_empezar++;
        };?>
    
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to let yii do pagination for you,just use a criteria for fetching your model and give it an instance of [CPagination](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination) .

you can also define a css class and assign it to your gridview or whatever using "htmlOptions".like:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
        'id' => 'my-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'summaryText'=>'', // hide summary
        'htmlOptions' => array(
          'class' => 'someClass',
          'style' => 'width: 600px;height: 300px;',
         ),
    ));
```

here is a [good example.](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25901-pagination-solution-simple-and-complex-ways/)

hope this helps.

UPDATE :or you can :

first in your controller,

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
...
$pages=new CPagination($count);

    // results per page
    $pages->pageSize=10;
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

    $models = Books::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $this->render('index', array(
       'models' => $models,
       'pages' => $pages
    ));
```

and then in your view,

```
<?php foreach($models as $model): ?>
    $this->renderPartial('_gallery' , array('model' => $model));
<?php endforeach; ?>

// display pagination
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'pages' => $pages,
```

)) ?>

Comment: Thanks tinyByte, I also think that the best way is to let yii do pagination but I don't know how to do it. My problem is that in this case I don't have model! I create only the gallery view manually....and I put the gallery.php in protected/views/site/gallery.php  Should I create a model? Could you help me?

Comment: Yes I think you should use a data provider, or at least a model for better managing and populating your data.then you could renderPartial that model with your gallery.it's much easier this way.

Comment: Thanks tinyByte, but could you tell me how do it? Could you tell me what I have to write in the model?

Comment: Thanks tinyByte. To be honest, I don't know what are searching for hehe. I only want to create a image gallery with pagination. I tried your example, but as I told you, I don't have any model and the code produce a warning "include(Books.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ". Besides, I had to include this line `$count=Books::model()->count($criteria);` after `$criteria = new CDbCriteria;` Could you help me?

Comment: I assume that you have stored your images somewhere, and you have a model, for accessing your information.the Books in my answer was just an example.you should have used your own model name instead of that!

Comment: Hi tinyByte, I updated may main post. I don't use any model to display the images, I only have a code in gallery.php to display them. I don't know how to create a model. Please, if you think that I should have a model, tell me how to construct the model.

Comment: if you want to use yiis amazingly easy and powerful features of this framework, you better learning! I suggest you start by doing a blog as is described in http://www.yiiframework.com/files/yii-blog-1.1.0.pdf. it has all the fundamental one would need. my first yii book! I can't help you any further.Good luck!

Comment: just doing my part as a tinyByte in this whole lot of bytes!